# Moving from JSF/Spring to Rest API + Angular

Tags: spring, angular, rest, jsp, jsf

There is a project that is built using JSF with Spring Integration.
See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsf/jsf_spring_integration.htm to get an idea.
JSP is used for the html templates. Managed beans (part of JSF) make use of Spring beans as a managed property, which in turn drive business logic. The goal is to rip apart this project and split it into a RESTful service and Angular front end.
What is the best way to do this without re-writing everything. Which components can I get rid of, and which components can be re-used? If I use Spring Boot for building the REST API, can I re-use the Spring beans?

Edit: I am new to most of these technologies.

Answer (score 1):

Exposing your domain model through REST should be relatively straight forward using Spring/JPA, whatever. You should learn about DTOs and especially as it relates to problems about "Lazy Initialization" under Hibernate/JPA/Spring Data, etc.

Secondarily understand the concept of views into the domain model. E.g., shipping looks at the database differently than marketing. Same database, different "facades" or business layers with different set of DTOs.

Conceptually, reproducing a JSF front end in Angular is something that is both "the same thing" and "completely different" at the same time. The key difference, IMHO, will be the JavaScript concepts and paradigms underlying Angular/React/Vue or whatever you want to use on the Front End.

Consider that an AngularJS/React/Vue front end might be better off running on top of node.js in a separate container or server, and might have different databases that it accesses on its own such as loyalty points or currency conversion, etc. Don't be afraid to let the frontend folks "be" the application instead of the backend folks. On the backend, try not to lose information. For example, if a customer adds 3 items, then changes 1, then places the order, that's 3 separate pieces of information, not 1 order. This is important for business analytics and customer service, which are business facing services as opposed to client facing services.

As a Java developer I tend to feel Angular/JS developers do a completely different and non-overlapping job than me. I feel the same way towards HTML/CSS folks. As such, I don't recommend you try being both, you will stretch yourself too thin. However, a good working knowledge on a smaller project, such as you are suggesting, is certainly useful.

Welcome to SO. Your post will probably be closed/ignored for being to broad, etc. Very specific questions and answers are what this site is about. GL.

Comment: Thanks. As a clarification, the project is actually pretty huge. The link provided is just an example.

Comment: Secondarily learn/understand the concept of views into the domain model. E.g., shipping looks at the database differently than marketing. Same database, different "facades" or business layers and a different set of DTOs to go with it. See edits.